# Is there a difference between "feedstock" and "raw material"?

Tags: difference

Say, we have a vitamin mix, which we produce in large volumes and sell to animal fodder producers. Would we call our product "raw material" or "feedstock", should we desire to write a specification for it?

Should we name our specification

> Specification of Raw Material by CompanyName

or

> Specification of Feedstock by CompanyName

It's a translation question. In Russian, there's only one word, "сырье", for this particular meaning slot, so I'm a bit curious.

Comment: I would call it a **feed additive**.

Comment: @TRomano - nice, thanks! A [feed additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_additive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like TRomano already answered the question for your specific application, but to answer the question about the difference:
'Feedstock' is a little more specific than 'raw material'.  A feedstock is a particular type of raw material.  Raw material can encompass the entirety of what goes into making a product.  For instance, fabric, thread, dye, and buttons, are all raw material for making a shirt.

Feedstock is usually a single, uniform, raw material that is given as an input into a machine or process, usually in large quantities.  So in the shirt example, the fabric could be used as feedstock for a machine that quickly cuts out the pattern.

Other examples would plastic pellets fed into a machine to put into molds, or metal bars fed into a machine to be cut and lathed.